# React Native Deep Link Passes Undefined Parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking

I have implemented deep link navigation with `react-navigation` (v6) in my RN app, but I am unable to pass the parameters. When I open my app with `app://profile/123`, my param `123` is passed as `undefined` in navigation state.

Currently my `linking.ts` looks like this:

```
const config = {
  screens: {
    BottomNavigator: {
      screens: {
        ProfileNavigator: {
          screens: {
            ProfileScreen: {
              path: 'profile/:id',
              parse: {
                id: (id) => `${id}`,
              },
              exact: true,
            },
          },
        },
        SearchNavigator: { screens: { SearchScreen: 'search/:id' } },
      },
    },
  },
};

const linking = {
  prefixes: ['whitelabel://app'],
  config,
};

export default linking;
```

I am trying to pass `id` to `profile` screen. The screen is passed correctly and opens the app on the right page, but the id is not passed through and returns `undefined`.

This is what I get from navigation state when the page opens:

```
{"index": 0, "key": "stack-jrLYL7iuBFvpeerYqTdcp", "routeNames": ["Profile"], "routes": [{"key": "Profile-lju0Bmsahv4w_wdmRUlMS", "name": "Profile", "params": undefined}], "stale": false, "type": "stack"}
```

Comment: Your linking config says `ProfileScreen`, but your log says `Profile`. They don't seem like the same screens.

Comment: wow, thank you! such a rookie mistake :(